# Cloudera Manager - HDFS Free Space Health Issues Troubleshoot

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, spark-graphx

I have a cluster configured of two hosts -

[image: Hosts configurations :]

It seems the jobs I am running are creating huge logs and one of my hdfs datanode shows critical health issue as -

[image: Critical health issue for one of the hdfs data node -]

**Four Things :**

1. How I can cleanup these logs and make the space free? Is deleting them manually from /var/log/hadoop-hdfs, a good idea?

[image: hadoop-hdfs status]

2. As Above /var/log/hadoop-hdfs directory is only 610 MB where does the space in hdfs getting occupied?
3. How I can configure the log files to get deleted periodically?
4. I have HDFS, Spark and YARN - MR2 services up and running they all are creating their own logs. I wish to clean up those as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into hdfs -

To get which directory is having what size execute :
`hadoop fs -du -h /user/`

**Spark service log creation:**

Logs created by Spark location identified, deleted manually and cluster is back in its healthy state -

Spark on creates logs in HDFS at location -

```
/user/spark/applicationHistory
```

The log files size was 129GB.(deleted)

commands used - (As -rm moves files to Trash, we need to -rm it from Trash also in order clean up properly)

```
$ hadoop fs -rm /user/spark/applicationHistory/*

$ hadoop fs -rm -r  /user/cloudera/.Trash/Current
```